# Invalid Configuration Error in Craft CMS 3 using Nitro 2

Tags: config, nitro

I'm getting into Nitro 2 and so far loving it. I decided to create a scaffolding project to jump start other projects. Along the way, I ran into this error:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
/Users/cbad/websites/nitro/core/cms/web/cpresources doesn’t exist or isn’t writable by PHP.
```

The path exists and the permissions, look correct. They are drwxr-xr-x. I removed the contents of cpresrouces based on another solution found on google but didn't help. I'm missing something!

I was syncing my .env file and general.php when this began. In .env I made WEB_ROOT_PATH like this:

```
WEB_ROOT_PATH=/Users/cbad/websites/nitro/core/cms/web/
```

In general.php I did this:

```
'resourceBasePath' => App::env('WEB_ROOT_PATH').'cpresources',
```

If it helps, here are the permissions on the folders. They seem to be the same as those on a site that doesn't get this error:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 cbad  staff    64 Mar  7 16:55 assets
drwxr-xr-x  2 cbad  staff    64 Mar  7 16:27 cpresources
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 cbad  staff   604 Feb  5 20:12 index.php
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 cbad  staff  1202 Feb  5 20:12 web.config
```

It seems to resolve to the correct location, but I get the error listed above. Is it obvious what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This path is on your host machine but this isn't how docker *sees* things. To Nitro, the location of the folder is `/app/web/cpresources`.

Without going into too much details, I'd recommend going with [an alias](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#aliases) instead of hard-setting your `webroot` the way you are currently doing it. Doing so will make your scaffolding just *work* without having to change this path every time.

In your `config/general.php` define your `webroot` alias like this:

```php
'aliases' => [
    'webroot' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/web'
],
```

You can then remove `'resourceBasePath' => App::env('WEB_ROOT_PATH').'cpresources',` altogether since [its default value](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#resourcebasepath) is already correct.

This alias will also be handy for setting things like File System Path on your volumes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes total sense and I shouldn't have missed it. And the use of a an alias with dirname is just a superior solution for what I'm doing!